# Why some vertex on weight paint aren't painted

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights, vertex-paint

I think it's very self explanatory. When I try to paint some vertex in the weight painting mode they refuse to be painted. I have the weight normalized and tried painting with auto-normalice on and off, with mirror and without it, isolating the mesh with face or vertex selection.
Tried in 2.8 and 2.81 Alpha.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgDKL.jpg

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_33LFSt5vYAAiFWkQ5F7rpAhXdhSMrg

I'm very desesperated because it'sso arbitrary and random.

Comment: Go to Edit mode and assign some weight to all the vertices, then you should be able to weight paint them all... not sure what is the reason though.

Comment: I did that, it works, but when I try to smooth the weight paint or paint it again it goes blue again.